# Pagination Ajax with numbers and points

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

My pagination is working, but when I have for example 20 pages the pagination numbers breaks my HTML page.

How do I minimize the pagination numbers for 5 and dynamically insert `...` before and after indicating that there are more pages in the pagination?

PHP

```
public function paging($query,$records_per_page)
{
    $starting_position=0;
    if(isset($_GET["page_no"]))
    {
        $starting_position=($_GET["page_no"]-1)*$records_per_page;
    }
    $query2=$query." limit $starting_position,$records_per_page";
    return $query2;
}

public function paginglink($query,$records_per_page)
{

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $total_no_of_records = $stmt->rowCount();


    if($total_no_of_records > 0)
    {
        ?><ul class="pagination"><?php
        $total_no_of_pages=ceil($total_no_of_records/$records_per_page);

        $current_page = 0;

        if(isset($_GET["page_no"]))
        {                   
            $current_page=$_GET["page_no"];
        }

            echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='?page_no=1'>First</a></li>";


        for($i=1;$i<=$total_no_of_pages;$i++)
        {
            if($i==$current_page)
            {
                echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='?page_no=".$i."' style='color:red;'>".$i."</a></li>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='?page_no=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
            }
        }

            echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='?page_no=".$total_no_of_pages."'>Last</a></li>";

        ?></ul><?php
    }
}
```

**AJAX**

```
$('.page-link').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var url = $(this).data('href');

   $.ajax({
         url: url,
         success: function (response) {

           var html = $('<h1/>', {html : response}).find('#paginacao-ajax');
           $('#paginacao-ajax').html( html )              

         }
   });
})
```

I'm trying to understand how to do something like:

For example there are 50 pages in total

if the page has just been loaded

```
  [Fist] [1][2][3][4][5] [...] [Last]
```

If you are viewing page 8

```
  [Fist] [...] [8][9][10][11][12] [...] [Last]
```

If you have already arrived in the last 5 pages

```
  [Fist] [...] [46][47][48][49][50] [Last]
```